# The Poisson Process and different distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Fix a strictly positive real number $\lambda$.

Suppose $S_1<S_2<S_3< \dots$ are the instances of a Poisson process having intensity $\lambda$. Fix a non-negative integer $n$ and define a sequence of random variables by $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2, \dots , \epsilon_k , \dots$ by 
$$\epsilon_k = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if there exists an r such that $S_r \in (\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n})$} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

What is the distribution of $\epsilon_k$?

Fix some positive integer $n$. What is the distribution of $M=\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon_k$?

Let $N$ be the number of instances of the Poisson process occurring before time $1$. What is the distribution of $N$?

Prove that $\mathbb{P}(M \neq N) \leq n(1-e^{- \lambda/n} - \frac{\lambda}{n}e^{- \lambda/n}) \leq \frac{\lambda^2}{n}$ if $n \geq \lambda$.

I think $\epsilon_k$ follows the Bernoulli distribution, $M$ follows the Binomial distribution, and $N$ follows the Geometric distribution. Am I correct for these pars?

Would anybody help me to prove the given inequality?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: the parenthesis $(1-e^{- \lambda/n} - \frac{\lambda}{n}e^{- \lambda/n})$ is the probability that there are at least two Poisson events in any given interval of length $\lambda/n$.

Comment: @Did Sorry, I am still confused. How can I find $\mathbb{P}(M \neq N)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulation of the Poisson process is a bit different than what I normally see, so I will formulate it this way. Let $\{X(t):t\geqslant 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. Let $$S_n=\inf\{t:X(t)=n\}$$ be the arrival times. For a positive integer $n$, let $$\varepsilon_k=\begin{cases}1,& \text{if } X\left(\frac kn\right) - X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)>0\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
You're correct in that $\varepsilon_k$ has a Bernoulli distribution, with success parameter
$$
\begin{align*}
p &= \mathbb P\left(X\left(\frac kn\right) - X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)>0\right)\\ &= 1 - \mathbb P\left(X\left(\frac kn\right) - X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)=0\right)\\ 
&= 1 - \exp\left(-\lambda\left(\frac kn - \frac{k-1}n\right) \right)\\
&= 1 - \exp\left(\frac{-\lambda}n\right).
\end{align*}
 $$
From the independent increments property of the Poisson process, we have that the $\varepsilon_k$ are iid, so$$M=\sum_{k=1}^n\varepsilon_k\sim\operatorname{Bin}\left(n,1-\exp\left(\frac{-\lambda}n\right)\right).$$

$N$ is just $X(1)$, so it has a $\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ distribution.

As for $\mathbb P(M\ne N)$, this is the probability that at least one subinterval $\left(\frac{k-1}n,\frac kn\right)$ has more than one arrival, i.e.
$$\{M\ne N\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^n \left\{X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right) - X\left(\frac kn\right) \geqslant2\right\}, $$
and from the union bound we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(M\ne N)
&=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n\left\{X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right) - X\left(\frac kn\right) \geqslant2\right\} \right)\\
&\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb P\left(X\left(\frac{k-1}n\right) - X\left(\frac kn\right) \geqslant2\right)\\
&=n\mathbb P\left(X\left(\frac1n\right)\geqslant 2\right)\\
&=n\left(1-e^{-\frac\lambda n}-\frac\lambda n e^{-\frac\lambda n}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
From the inequality $1-x\leqslant e^{-x}$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
1 - e^{-\frac\lambda n} - \frac\lambda n e^{-\frac\lambda n}&\leqslant
\frac\lambda n - \frac\lambda ne^{-\frac\lambda n}\\
&=\frac\lambda n\left(1-e^{-\frac\lambda n}\right)\\
&\leqslant \left(\frac\lambda n\right)^2,
\end{align*}
$$
and the desired inequality is attained by multiplying by $n$.

Comment: What is the function $X$?

Comment: The number of arrivals in $(0,t]$.